# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when launching python3.11 in anaconda in hpc

Tags: python-3.x, wsl-2, hpc, anaconda3

I am facing a issue while launching Anaconda's python3.11 in hpc.
When I am doing ssh through the wsl's ubuntu 22.04 from window it is showing the segmentation fault core dumped error but when I am doing ssh through powershell it is not showing the error. So I didn't understand why is it so? It should be independent of the medium which I am using for ssh.

Comment: Had the same issue today: ssh with WSL to a Linux machine. The `/usr/bin/python` in the remote worked fine, but `python` (conda's python) failed. Interestingly, `python -I` (conda python in isolated mode) worked fine. Changing terminal emulator (such as a puTTy also fixed the issue)